# The TextView Doubles on Config/ Orientation Change: How do I fix?

Tags: android

This question has been asked before, but not answered completely for certain situations. When restoring the text of a multiLine textView, and during onConfig, how do I stop this annoying bug where the text doubles? After a number of Config changes, the text is so much, that the program has trouble handling it within the textView.

How do I stop this while still using onConfigChanged, and what is the correct way to transfer state to a new layout, while still using onConfig?

This answer could be a great help.

Thank You all.

JB.

Comment: thank you all for what? for someone answers and don't give a shit about their answers?

Answer (score 0):

if the `TextView` has an id you don't need to save the state.

"In order for the Android system to restore the state of the views in your activity, each view must have a unique ID, supplied by the android:id attribute."

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html